# OEM software / Windows Server advice

Tags: vpn, oem, windows-sbs

I need to set up a laptop as a server and I understand that I need a Windows Server OS to enable more than one simultaneous VPN connection. Correct? If so, would Windows Small Business Server do the trick? This seems to be the cheapest option.

When I've searched online for this software, the cheapest results have been for OEM editions.

Is this okay for my purposes?
Is this actually the full software and will it do what I need?

It seems cheap compared to the full edition. What's the catch?

Answer (score 0):

The catch is that according to the licence, you're only supposed to install the OS on a fresh system, and that the licence is not transferable between systems you own.Technically, while it will work, you'll likely violate the EULA by installing it on a laptop.

I also believe that SBS has a certain number of users supported - the "essentials" version supports up to 25, and the regular up to 75. If you exceed the number of users you are allowed, you may need to get additional CALs

Comment: I don't think he's transfering between systems.  Just wondering what an OEM license is.